# Disk space usage for each installed app in ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I need to show the each installed application disk space usage in my app like ios 8 Settings-> General -> Usage -> Manage Storage

I have searched here about this. But i didn't get any solution.

Pls suggest me is it possible? If yes, give the API reference link for this.

Comment: No, it isn't possible on a non-jailbroken device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access such information related to other apps.There is no API documented yet.